# Subset Data in R where a column must have 3 possibilities

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a data.frame which has 3 columns: Agents Name, Categorization(A, B, C or D) and Week Numbers i.e. Week1, Week2 etc.

The agents CAN be in multiple weeks having one of the 4 categorization. Currently I have data upto 10 weeks.

I want to make a subset that has "A" as Categorization and is available in all: Week8, Week9 and Week10 (the latest 3 weeks).

Currently I have built this function to achieve desired results:-

```
cautionAgentsLocator = function(classification){

cautionAgents = NA

if(classification == "Bad"){

 cautionAgents = combData[combData$ABCD.Categorization == "D", ]

 cautionAgents = cautionAgents[cautionAgents$Weeks == "Week8" | cautionAgents$Weeks == "Week9" | cautionAgents$Weeks == "Week10", ]

cautionAgents = cautionAgents[, c("Agent.Name", "SPD", "Normalized.Distribution", "ABCD.Categorization", "Weeks")]

}

if(classification == "Good"){

cautionAgents = combData[combData$ABCD.Categorization == "A", ]

cautionAgents = cautionAgents[cautionAgents$Weeks == "Week8" | cautionAgents$Weeks == "Week9" | cautionAgents$Weeks == "Week10", ]

cautionAgents = cautionAgents[, c("Agent.Name", "SPD", "Normalized.Distribution", "ABCD.Categorization", "Weeks")]

}


uniqueName = unique(cautionAgents$Agent.Name)

for(i in uniqueName){
count = nrow(cautionAgents[cautionAgents$Agent.Name == i, ])
missingWeeks = setdiff(c("Week8", "Week9", "Week10"), cautionAgents$Weeks[cautionAgents$Agent.Name == i])
if(count < 3){
  cautionAgents = cautionAgents[-which(cautionAgents$Agent.Name == i), ]
 }
}
```

Can this be achieved with a single line of code i.e single subsetting statement using *dplyr* or some better technique?

To create just a Chunk of the Data, here is the code:-

```
structure(list(Agent.Name = c("Christy Deruise", "Allen Voorhees", 
"Daniel Gonzalez Gaviria", "Denise Bradley", "Shimron Larose", 
"Tiana Morman", "James Cagle Jr", "Vicki Smith", "Donna Paskett", 
"Joan Balde"), ABCD.Categorization = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), Weeks = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Week1", "Week2", "Week3", 
"Week4", "Week5", "Week6", "Week7", "Week8", "Week9", "Week10"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

But then of course, the actual data has around 4000 rows where each Agent is present in multiple weeks having different categorization for each week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(ABCD.Categorization == "A") %>%
  group_by(Agent.Name) %>%
  filter(all(c("Week8", "Week9", "Week10") %in%  Weeks) & 
         Weeks %in% c(c("Week8", "Week9", "Week10")))
```

Comment: This is working. Except, I have to write additional code to remove the Rows which have Weeks other than c("Week8", "Week9", "Week10"). If you could kindly modify the code, I would mark you answer as Accepted. Thanks

Comment: @BasitTanvirKhan Updated the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

"Like this?

```
library(dplyr)
combData %>%
    filter(ABCD.Categorization == "A", Weeks %in% c("Week8", "Week9", "Week10")) %%>
    select(Agent.Name, ABCD.Categorization, Weeks)
```

Comment: This didn't work @Marcus. The issue with this is the same I pointed out in the comment of the answer above that with this code, even those Names appear which - for example - are in Week8 and Week10 but not in Week9.

Comment: I'm not following what your code does. I don't see where the function `cautionAgentsLocator` is ever called. Is the data you provided the expected output or input? Is it for `cautionAgents` or for `combData`?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. The first code snippet is the entire code for a single function "cautionAgentsLocator()". The reproducible data is a chunk of the original dataset on which, when the "cautionAgentsLocator()" is called, outputs the desired result as explained in the very beginning of the question. Kindly let me know if any more clarification is required. Thanks for the attempt.